# How to add templates to existing XSLT that uses for-each loops to generate HTML?

Tags: xslt

I have a stylesheet that generates HTML for XML files.

Example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="trial.xsl"?>
<wholeEnchilada>
  <Interface>
    <Messages>
      <Message name="blah">
        <Variable name="DialogIdentifier" dataType="UINT16"/>
        <Variable name="ReplyCount" dataType="UINT16"/>
        <Variable name="ReplyPeriod" dataType="UINT16"/>
      </Message>
      <Message>
        <Variable name="Uptime" dataType="UINT32"/>
        <Variable name="FaultIndicator" dataType="UINT32"/>
        <Variable name="OperatingMode" dataType="UINT8"/>
      </Message>
    </Messages>
  </Interface>
  <Interface>
    <Messages>
      <Message>
        <Variable name="vara" dataType="UINT64"/>
        <Variable name="varb" dataType="UINT8"/>
      </Message>
    </Messages>
  </Interface>
</wholeEnchilada>
```

Example stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
      <BODY>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
          <xsl:for-each select="Interface">
            <xsl:for-each select="Messages">
              <xsl:for-each select="Message">
                <TABLE BORDER="1">
                  <TR><TH>Field Name</TH><TH>Size</TH><TH>Offset</TH></TR>
                  <!-- Fields-->
                  <xsl:for-each select="Variable">
                    <TR>
                      <TD><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></TD>
                      <TD><xsl:value-of select="@size"/></TD>
                      <TD><xsl:value-of select="@offset"/></TD>
                    </TR>
                  </xsl:for-each> <!-- Fields-->
                </TABLE>
              <xsl:for-each select="Variable">
                <xsl:variable name="fieldSize" select="substring-after(@dataType,'INT') div 8"/>
                <TABLE BORDER="1">
                  <TR><TH>Name</TH>    <TH><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></TH></TR>
                  <TR><TD>Size</TD>    <TD><xsl:value-of select="$fieldSize"/></TD></TR>
                  <TR><TD>Offset</TD>  <TD><xsl:value-of select="Offset"/></TD></TR>
                  <TR><TD>DataType</TD><TD><xsl:value-of select="@dataType"/></TD></TR>
                </TABLE>
              </xsl:for-each>
                <hr size="10" noshade="true"/>
              </xsl:for-each>  <!-- Message -->
            </xsl:for-each> <!-- Messages -->
          </xsl:for-each> <!-- Interface -->
        </xsl:for-each> <!-- * -->
      </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My actualy stylesheet is ~300 lines long, and prints lots more attributes and navigates lots more structure than the sample given above.

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045459/xslt-table-lookup-and-sumpreceding-sibling) about how to calculate field sizes (INT8->1, INT16->2, INT32->4), and also variable offsets, where the first variable starts at 0, the next starts after the first, etc.  I think the question was answered, but unfortunately I've been complete unsuccessful in integrating the answer to generate HTML in my existing stylesheet.

My attempt at integrating [Alejandro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045459/xslt-table-lookup-and-sumpreceding-sibling/4045790#4045790) from his "Edit 3", but based on the output, I didn't do it right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="Variable">
        <xsl:param name="fieldOffset" select="0"/>
        <xsl:variable name="fieldSize" select="substring-after(@dataType,'INT') div 8"/>
        (<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>, <xsl:value-of select="$fieldSize"/>, <xsl:value-of select="$fieldOffset"/>)
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="size">
                <xsl:value-of select="$fieldSize"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="offset">
                <xsl:value-of select="$fieldOffset"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
        ((<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>, <xsl:value-of select="@size"/>, <xsl:value-of select="@offset"/>))
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Variable[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="fieldOffset" select="$fieldOffset + $fieldSize"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@fieldOffset"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <HTML>
          <BODY>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
              <xsl:for-each select="Interface">
                <xsl:for-each select="Messages">
                  <xsl:for-each select="Message">
                    <TABLE BORDER="1">
                      <TR><TH>Field Name</TH><TH>Size</TH><TH>Offset</TH></TR>
                      <!-- Fields-->
                      <xsl:for-each select="Variable">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]|following-sibling::*[1]"/>
                        <TR>
                          <TD><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></TD>
                          <TD><xsl:value-of select="@size"/></TD>
                          <TD><xsl:value-of select="@offset"/></TD>
                        </TR>
                      </xsl:for-each> <!-- Fields-->
                    </TABLE>
              <xsl:for-each select="Variable">
                <xsl:variable name="fieldSize" select="substring-after(@dataType,'INT') div 8"/>
                <TABLE BORDER="1">
                  <TR><TH>Name</TH>    <TH><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></TH></TR>
                  <TR><TD>Size</TD>    <TD><xsl:value-of select="$fieldSize"/></TD></TR>
                  <TR><TD>Offset</TD>  <TD><xsl:value-of select="Offset"/></TD></TR>
                  <TR><TD>DataType</TD><TD><xsl:value-of select="@dataType"/></TD></TR>
                </TABLE>
              </xsl:for-each>
                    <hr size="10" noshade="true"/>
                  </xsl:for-each>  <!-- Message -->
                </xsl:for-each> <!-- Messages -->
              </xsl:for-each> <!-- Interface -->
            </xsl:for-each> <!-- * -->
          </BODY>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Based on my diagnostic statements (which show up in parenthesis in the HTML output), the templates *are* being executed, I just don't know how to make the proper output from the templates show up in the HTML.  xsl:copy seems to be creating copies of the nodes and putting the new attributes @size and @offset in them, but not in a way that makes those attributes accessible to my `<xsl:value-of select="@size"/>` and `<xsl:value-of select="@offset"/>` statements.

Here's the HTML I'd like to get, for the first message in the XML file:

```
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Field Name</th><th>Size</th><th>Offset</th></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>DialogIdentifier</td><td>2</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ReplyCount</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ReplyPeriod</td><td>2</td><td>4</td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>

<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>DialogIdentifier</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Size</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offset</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DataType</td><td>UINT16</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>ReplyCount</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Size</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offset</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DataType</td><td>UINT16</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>ReplyPeriod</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Size</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Offset</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DataType</td><td>UINT16</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @KeyserSoze: Posting desired output will provide you better answers. Remember that the calculated size and offset are in $fieldSize and $fieldOffset. This is a FAQ: **You can't query the output tree**. You could declare a variable with the output, transform this to a source document with `node-set()` extension function, and then query it.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know xsl:copy copied to the output tree.  Docs don't really mention it: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying

Comment: @KeyserSoze - the spec section you linked to is under section 7, "Creating the Result Tree": "This section describes instructions that directly create nodes in the result tree." I wouldn't necessarily recommend the spec as a place to *learn* XSLT.

Comment: @LarsH: You wrote *I wouldn't necessarily recommend the spec as a place to learn XSLT*. Really? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055016/is-there-a-bug-in-my-xml-code-or-in-net/4055410#4055410) question and tell if the spec doesn't contain explanations for many FAQs.

Comment: @Alejandro: you're right it does, but it doesn't necessarily make those explanations easy to find when you need them, especially if you're not well-versed in XSLT already. You have to know the concepts, categories and terminology pretty well. Yes it's very profitable to read through the spec if you understand the concepts well. But it's not intended as a tutorial. I don't think you and I are in real disagreement -- it's just a question of for which situations and people the spec is an optimal next step for learning.

Comment: @LarsH: You wrote *But it's not intended as a tutorial*. I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="Message">
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Field Name</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Offset</th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Variable[1]"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Variable[1]" mode="table"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Variable">
        <xsl:param name="pOffset" select="0"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vSize"
                      select="substring-after(@dataType,'UINT') div 8"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$vSize"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pOffset"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Variable[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pOffset" select="$pOffset + $vSize"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Variable" mode="table">
        <xsl:param name="pOffset" select="0"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vSize"
                      select="substring-after(@dataType,'UINT') div 8"/>
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Size</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$vSize"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Offset</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$pOffset"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>DataType</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@dataType"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Variable[1]"
                             mode="table">
            <xsl:with-param name="pOffset" select="$pOffset + $vSize"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Field Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Offset</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>DialogIdentifier</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ReplyCount</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ReplyPeriod</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>DialogIdentifier</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Offset</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType</td>
            <td>UINT16</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ReplyCount</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Offset</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType</td>
            <td>UINT16</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ReplyPeriod</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Offset</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType</td>
            <td>UINT16</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Field Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Offset</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Uptime</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FaultIndicator</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>OperatingMode</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Uptime</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Offset</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType</td>
            <td>UINT32</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>FaultIndicator</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Offset</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType</td>
            <td>UINT32</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>OperatingMode</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Offset</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType</td>
            <td>UINT8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Field Name</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Offset</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>vara</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>varb</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>vara</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Offset</td>
            <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType</td>
            <td>UINT64</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>varb</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Size</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Offset</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DataType</td>
            <td>UINT8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Too much to go through right now but here are a couple resources and tips.

1. Here's the link to the w3c school's
   online tutorial:
   http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp
2. If you're up to it, or desperate
   enough, you can also review the
   specs. for additional details:
   http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt
3. Use Firefox. It shows where the
   errors are and will help you greatly
   when debugging.