# Is there a bug in my XML code or in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I just ran into an issue where my code was parsing xml fine but once I added in a second node it started to load incorrect data. The real code spans a number of classes and projects but for the sample I've put together the basics of what's causing the issue

When the code runs I'd expect the output to be the contents of the second Task node, but instead the contents of the first node is output. It keeps pulling from the first occurrence of the EmailAddresses node despite how when you check the settings object its inner xml is that of the second Task node. The call to `SelectSingleNode("//EmailAddresses")` is where the issue happens.

I have two ways around this issue

1. Remove the leading slashes from the EmailAddresses XPath expression
2. Call `Clone()` after getting the Task or Settings node

Solution 1 works in this case but I believe this will cause other code in my project to stop working.

Solution 2 looks more like a hack to me than a real solution.

MY question is am I in fact doing this correctly and there's a bug in .NET (all versions) or am I just pulling the XML wrong?

The c# code

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\temp\Sample.xml");

var tasks = doc.SelectSingleNode("Server/Tasks");

foreach (XmlNode threadNode in tasks.ChildNodes)
{
    if (threadNode.Name.ToLower() != "thread")
    {
        continue;
    }

    foreach (XmlNode taskNode in threadNode.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (taskNode.Name.ToLower() != "task" || taskNode.Attributes["name"].Value != "task 1")
        {
            continue;
        }

        var settings = taskNode.SelectSingleNode("Settings");

        var emails = settings.SelectSingleNode("//EmailAddresses");

        Console.WriteLine(emails.InnerText);
    }
}
```

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Server>
    <Tasks>
        <Thread>
            <Task name="task 2">
                <Settings>
                    <EmailAddresses>task 2 data</EmailAddresses>
                </Settings>
            </Task>
        </Thread>
        <Thread>
            <Task name="task 1">
                <Settings>
                    <EmailAddresses>task 1 data</EmailAddresses>
                </Settings>
            </Task>
        </Thread>
    </Tasks>
</Server>
```

Comment: The likelihood that it's a bug in .NET is very small.

Comment: I think in XPath, //EmailAddresses would return a collection of XMLnodes. Have you tried doc.SelectNodes("//EmailAddresses") and then get the second one?

Comment: Doubt yourself first, last, and always.

Comment: @SaeedAlg, I have no idea what you're asking me.  All I'm saying is that the liklihood that the bug lay in his code far outweighs the chances of .NET being at fault.

Comment: @duffymo, I'm not agree with your first sentence but I'm agree with Robert Harvey, may be I can't understand what you saying:D I'd see your profile you're a great man

Comment: Your English is far better than my Arabic, I'm sure.  Great man?  No.  All I'm telling the questioner (and you) is that it's much more likely that any bugs we find are due to what we ourselves put in our code.  The people who write Java, .NET, Spring, etc. are better developers than we are and have large audiences that rapidly find and identify bugs.  Is that clearer?

Comment: @duffymo, I'm Persian not Arab:D I say you are great because of your types of activities, not your rep, but there are too many bugs which will be found by beginner and intermediate users in each release of .net, and we are also audiences.

Comment: My apologies, Saeed.  I'm an ignorant American.  I'm saying that those beginner and intermediate users will find bugs in their own code that swamp the few that they'll find in .NET or Java, so my advice is to always assume that they are at fault before they blame the virtual machine they're using.  Do a quick survey of questions on SO that ask if a particular problem is caused by user or framework code.  I'd bet that more than 99% of the time the error is in the user code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

> `//` is short for
>   `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. For
>   example, `//para` is short for
>   `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para`
>   and so will select any para element in
>   the document (even a para element that
>   is a document element will be selected
>   by `//para` since the document element
>   node is a child of the root node);

And also:

> A location step of `.` is short for
>   `self::node()`. This is particularly
>   useful in conjunction with `//`. For
>   example, the location path `.//para`
>   is short for
>
> ```
> self::node()/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para
> ```
>
> and so will select all para descendant
>   elements of the context node.

Instead of:

```
var settings = taskNode.SelectSingleNode("Settings");

var emails = settings.SelectSingleNode("//EmailAddresses");
```

Use:

```
var emails = taskNode.SelectSingleNode("Settings/EmailAddresses");
```

Answer (score 3):

The `//` [XPath expression](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) does not do what you think it does. It `selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are`.

In other words, it's not limited by the current scope, it actually crawls back up the document tree and starts matching from the root element.

To select the first `<EmailAddresses>` element in your current scope, you only need:

```
var emails = settings.SelectSingleNode("EmailAddresses");
```